# C# Only allowing qr code to be scanned once

Tags: c#, winforms, qr-code

We use QR codes on our products. Each QR code is virtually identical except for a unique serial number.

I'm writing a C# Win Form program for building product KITS. They then scan off each product within that KIT to complete the Order. Some KITS contain multiples of the same product. **I want to prevent the user from simply scanning the same QR code for a product with multiples in a KIT.**

I will be creating a database for this Win App to store which qr codes have been scanned off the total amount needed for the KIT.

To ensure that the same QR code isn't scanned, would I be correct in assuming I'd simply need to run a check against the serial numbers previously scanned in the database? If so, how is the most efficient way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: For efficiency, couldn't you cache the most recently scanned items and check against the cache?

Comment: @DannyEllisJr. We're going to be storing each scanned qr code in a database table so that we're able to run reports on the products scanned for each Order. So it'd be better to extract them and insert them into the table and the query the table to make sure that the serial number doesn't already exist

Comment: Persisting to a database does not preclude the use of some form of in-memory caching. Without a more complete understanding of your scenario, I couldn't say how to engineer that precisely, but it is doable.

Comment: So from your other comments, it looks like the SN is 5 digits. Have you thought about cacheing them as scanned in an array and checking if the value exists?

Answer (score 0):

It depends how the QR Code is stored in your database and how each QR code differs. Is it stored as data/an image? What exact data is being encoded onto the QR code?

You mention that the QR codes are virtually identical, but they have a unique serial number. Is this serial number stored in the QR Code? If so then after decoding you can simply search for the serial number in the database.

Comment: The QR codes are stored as data in the database. I need to extract the end of the string, after the last comma - `PO00283,ME-CAL-TOL-150,03/05/2015 11:11:31,14054`

Comment: To note I've created a regex to extract the serial number from the end of the qr code.

Answer (score 0):

As far as efficiency goes, use the unique serial number as the identifier column in your table. Then, either query for that serial number, and only approve the scan if the query does not return anything. It is not completely safe though, as once you're trying to write the value to the table, it may already have been written by a different caller.

On the other hand, if you have a unique constraint on the column, you can just attempt to insert the scanned serial number - and let it fail if it already exists.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a single user/computer being used for scanning each kit, and the process of scanning each kit has a definitive beginning or ending, and the data being stored isn't massive, and each kit scanned will be scanned in a single session, I would store each item scanned in an in-memory collection until the entire kit is scanned, then write the completed kit to the database asynchronously.

- You can check the each new code against the in-memory collection.
- This helps to make sure you don't have partial collections (orphaned data) in the database.
- Makes it much more efficient to remove erroneously scanned items.